# escape special characters in regex using php

Tags: php, regex, char, preg-match

how can i escape characters like this: `'` `(` `)` in preg_match regex, because i have problem running this code:

```
preg_match("'javascript:window.open('(.*?)')'si", $source, $export);
```

the `$source` variable have this value:    `javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com')`

and i want to take out http://www.google.com from `$source` and put it into `$export`.

Comment: preg_quote() ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: I have a `preg_quote()` example in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647323/escape-special-characters-in-regex-using-php/7647518#7647518). It's interesting what it reveals.

Answer (score 1):

You can just extract your `$link` string using [`sscanf`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/sscanf):

```
$source = "javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com')";

sscanf($source, "javascript:window.open('%[^']", $link);

echo $link;
```

([Demo](http://codepad.org/hyNRiZWG)) The benefit is that the syntax is easier to understand than with regular expressions and you can assign values to variables directly.

In case you want to use regular expressions, you need to quote special characters ([`preg_quote`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/preg_quote)) before you create your pattern. This needs more work, as you must build the regex pattern prior running it:

```
# bare pattern, placeholder for matching group:
$pattern = "javascript:window.open('%s')"; 

# quote the pattern, you use ' as delimiter, it needs to be quoted
$pattern = preg_quote($pattern, "'");

# build full regex with delimiters, modifiers and inserting your match group
$pattern = sprintf("'$pattern'is", '(.*?)');

# run it
preg_match($pattern, $source, $export);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dCbLGG)

This will result in the following pattern:

```
'javascript\:window\.open\(\'(.*?)\'\)'is
```

Or as a valid PHP string:

```
$pattern = '\'javascript\\:window\\.open\\(\\\'(.*?)\\\'\\)\'is';
```

or your example:

```
preg_match('\'javascript\\:window\\.open\\(\\\'(.*?)\\\'\\)\'is', $source, $export);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always escape characters with the backslash (`\`). In your case:

```
preg_match("'javascript:window.open\(\'(.*?)\'\)'si", $source, $export);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to excape any special character by `\`. Please try this:

```
$source = "javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com')";
preg_match("/javascript:window.open\\('(.*?)'\\)/si", $source, $export);
print_r($export);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this character to scape before the character you want to use 
**"\"**

If there are characters (.,:,(,),\,/,-,[,],#,...) in your string and you want them to match the string you need to have them in the pattern **scape by "\"**

```
 (\.,\:,\(,\),\\\\,\/,\-,\[,\],\#,...)
```